# Is ForeignKey concept a violation of SRP?

Tags: django, design-patterns, database-design, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I'd like to illustrate the general nature of my question with a Django sample:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name='member', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Team(models.Model):
    pass
```

Here, the goal is to create a relationship representing the fact that *a single person can be associated with one and only one team*.

But, **doesn't it violate SRP that Person entity is aware of Team entity**, and not vice-versa?

I would rather write something like

```
class Person(models.Model):
    pass

class Team(models.Model):
    members = models.OneToMany(Person, related_name='team', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

As a consequence, whenever a new *Entity*-to-Person relationship is introduced (or, an existing one wiped out) there'd be no need to update Person model.

Comment: For a start, that sounds like semantics; a Person is a member of a team. But more importantly, you would still need some way of storing the team_id on the database table underlying Person; how would you do that without making a change to the Person model.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, what do I need a team_id in Person table for, since I can store member_id (UNIQUEly constrained) in Team table instead?

Comment: But there are *many* members in each team. How can you store many member_ids?

Comment: @DanielRoseman, you're right, I can't :) Still, since the issue is essentially about Django semantics, it would be great to have that feature implemented as follows: Whenever I want to express it in an "SPR"-way, a third table -- something like `TeamToMembers` -- is created, with OneToOne relationship to Person, and a ForeignKey to Team, plus extra convenience methods emulating standard CRUD operations, but with regards to that table.

Comment: I guess, the question should be closed now. Thank you, @DanielRoseman, for clarifications.

Comment: @reaanb, SRP says nothing about duplicate responsibilities.

Comment: @jaco0646, but this case is not about redundancies -- it's about entities knowing more than they should, burdened with extra responsibilities...

Comment: Whether a person "is aware of" their team (whatever you think you mean by that) is irrelevant. Application entities are not application/implementation objects. What matters is whether you have users dealing with persons that aren't dealing with (aware of) teams. If so, you give them a model of persons without a team field. Others might need a model of persons and a model of teams (and there are various ways you can so design). Their Person could have team for convenience. Restrict each's access to classes/tables if they share a database. DMBSs have per-user views of shared databases for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Associations between objects don't define responsibilities. Obviously, you don't want to associate unrelated objects to a given entity, but this is more about a good design rather than a thing about responsibilities.

Responsibilities are more tied with *behaviors*. That is, you don't want a table trying to manage a team, but a team member with assigned role of *team leader* should be able to manage teams. So team leaders manage team members and their needs, while a *team leader*  couldn't also define how to pay a team member's salary.

BTW, it might depend on what paradigms and patterns you really use to implement your solution. I would be concerned about *behaviors* if you implement your entities as [*active records*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern). Otherwise, most functionalities will go into a [service layer](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html).